# Getting the root path of all mounted SD cards

Tags: android

I need to get the root path of all mounted SD cards. I am attempting to use getExternalFilesDirs(null) as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). The elements in this array end up being something like this: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package name/files and /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/package name/files. So in order to get the root path of each I am using:

```
File[] storage = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
for (File file : storage) {
    String mPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    int end = mPath.indexOf("/Android");
    mPath = mPath.substring(0,end);
    // do things here
}
```

For my purposes, this works fine however, it seems like there should be a cleaner way. Can anyone shed some light on a cleaner solution?

Comment: "it seems like there should be a cleaner way" -- [removable media was not part of the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), and Android 4.4 only gives you access via `getExternalFilesDirs()`. In particular, Android does not tell you "the root path of all mounted SD cards", and your algorithm may not be reliable across Android devices and future OS updates. Mostly, Android 4.4 does not provide root paths on removable media to you because they are inaccessible on Android 4.4.

Comment: `removable media was not part of the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4`. Well whatever that means. But we did not mind as all our devices with lower Android versions had micro SD cards installed and we could read and write them. We could also connect USB sticks and read and write them. `and Android 4.4 only gives you access via getExternalFilesDirs()`. Well Google may allow that but I can experiment here with three such kitkat devices now and getExternalFilesDirs() returns only one dir and not that of the removable. And apps cannot write to the card anymore. Only some systemsapp like camera.

Comment: But that not even on all devices. `removable media was not part of the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4,` ??? well don't say that again please.